# nginx try_files location Configuration?

Tags: nginx

I am in the process of writing a directory listings script in Slim 3 Framework. I am having a problem that Slim 3 is not getting the request for a file download when it exists due to the 'try_files' directive in the configuration. Once I change the order of the 'try_files' it then fails to process any .php file for that matter.

Here is the current block of the configuration:

```
location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
```

this was the tried configuration (and failed - it would serve up a .bin file with the contents of my index.php instead of processing it):

```
location / {
        try_files /index.php$is_args$args $uri;
    }
```

Ultimately, I want my Slim 3 script to capture the request and do something with it instead of simply serving it up by the web server.

Here is the entire vhost configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name debian9;
    index index.php;
    error_log /home/patrick/html/indexmeta.error.log;
    access_log /home/patrick/html/indexmeta.access.log;
    root /home/patrick/html/indexmeta/public;

    location ~ \.php {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    location / {
        try_files /index.php$is_args$args $uri;
    }

}

server {
   listen 8800;
   root /home/patrick/html/phpmyadmin;

   location / {
       index index.php index.html index.htm;   
   }

   location ~ \.php$ {
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   }

}
```

Comment: Slightly confused here. Is Slim3 a PHP framework? Never heard of it. Do you have appropriate blocks to execute PHP? My try_files for Wordpress is "try_files $uri $uri/ index.php?$args;" - yours is missing the ? and the & I would expect if you're trying to pass parameters, but I could be wrong there.

Comment: @Tim when $args is set (has args in it) then $is_args is set to '?'.

Comment: @tkrn please post your whole vhost config.

Comment: The last parameter to the `try_files` directive is a URI or response code. See [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details. The `/index.php` is a URI and can only work in the last position for this `location`.

Answer (score 1):

If I rewrite all files to the index.php page as a parameter, I get my desired output. Here is the nginx configuration code:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 last;
}
```